# Are d electrons ever delocalized in metallic bonding

Tags: bond, electronic-configuration, transition-metals

It has been my understanding that delocalized electrons that participate in metallic bonds come from the highest primary energy level, specifically from the s and p sublevels and that electrons in d orbitals (from one level lower) do not delocalize.

Palladium however, has its $5d^{10}$ electrons IN its highest energy level because it has no 6s electrons, and yet Palladium clearly has electron delocalization.  So do d sublevel electrons delocalize in general?  In any metal elements? (such as in Palladium).

Comment: d-block elements bond with s and d electrons not p.

Comment: I didn't say d-block.  I included p because Lawrencium has a p valence electron.  Sources I have found say that d do not dissociate in metallic bonding but they obviously do in Pd.